# Assigning a React app function to a window variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React app versions residing on the same page. One is a newer app (React 15) and the other one (React 16). Right now, they are pass data to each other via global variables. I was wondering if there is a way to call a function from my react 15 app to my react 16 app through a global variable assigned with the function from the old app upon mounting.

Here's what I have:

**React 15**

```
...
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log('[componentDidUnmount]')
    window.playFunction = this.restoreAllTimelines;
    window.pauseFunction = this.pauseAllTimelines;

    console.log(window.playFunction + " " + window.pauseFunction)

    window.mainContainer = {
      addStateValidator: this.addStateValidator,
    };
    this.props.start();
  }
...
```

**React 16**

```
getScreenshotHandler = () => {
    // These 2 lines communicate with content_script.js that's from the extension
    var data = { type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "Screenshot Request" };
    // window.postMessage(data, "*");
    window.parent.postMessage(data, "*");

    window.pauseFunction();

    this.notify(true, "Screenshot Taken. Nice!")
    if (this.state.pauseOnShot) {
        triggerPlay();
    }
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.playFunction();
    if (this.props.pauseOnShot) {
        triggerPlay();
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
...
<script>
window.r15r16URLPipe=null;
window.playFunction=null;
window.pauseFunction=null;
<script/>

<div id="root"></div> //React 15
<div id="screenshot"></div> // React 16
...
```

Any input will be appreciated. Thanks!